# How to fit the number of data in a labeled dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

supposed my dataset

```
    Name Num Label
0   K    10    0
1   K    21    0 
2   K    31    0
3   K    41    1
4   Y    9     0
5   Y    19    0
6   Y    14    1
7   B    33    0
8   B    43    0    
9   B    77    1
10  B    89    1
11  S    14    0
12  S    20    1
13  S    33    1
14  S    55    1
```

so I used pivot table, using count

`df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns='Label', values='Num', aggfunc = 'count')`

result

```
COUNT
Name   0(label)    1(label)
K      3           1
Y      2           1
B      2           1
S      1           3
```

I need to compare the two values(label : 0, label : 1), but I want to calculate after setting the count value.

However, many values try to put median values.

For example, in the case of K, there are 3 values labeled 0 and 1 value labeled 1.
The value labeled '0' to be compared to the value labeled '1' is the median value of 21 (of 11, 21, 31).

Above dataframe, As the example data, the value of count is 1 on one side, but the value of count may be many.

For example, the number of values labeled as '0' may be 10 and the number of values labeled as '1' may be 30.

Even in this case, in order to compare and match 10 values, it is desired to use 10 medians among 30 values(labeld dataset '1'.)

*If you don't understand, please leave a comment.

**The result of count for the final result should be as follows.**

```
COUNT(The median value is applied to the value with a small count.)
Name   0(label)    1(label)
K      1           1
Y      1           1
B      1           1
S      1           1
```

Or is it possible to get the median of the number I want when there are multiple values?

for example, values = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

If I want 4 medians that values -> 4,5,6,7

thank you for reading.